# Django: make a page without reloading

Tags: ajax, django

I want to make a page which appears from 1 to 10 but without reloading the page and have one second between each number.

I've been reading and seems to need ajax (I'm new to this), but using functions that sound complex, I just want a section on my page with a `<div>` showing those numbers from 1 to 10 without reload the webpage.

Any guide or basic example would help me greatly!

Thank you!

Comment: use AJAX to do this.

Comment: Is Django a requirement? This seems like pure Javascript.

Comment: There is no need for Ajax here, a simple JS counter will be enough. Nothing to do with Django though.

Comment: I need to use django to implement it in a project

Comment: am looking for a base to replace it with other values, just looking for something simple, thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

In case you are looking for something that can help you replace values in your HTML with new data from the back-end, here's how you can do it.

**xyz_template.html**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            {{number}}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**pqr.js**

```
    var current_number = $(".container").val();
    var c = getCookie('csrftoken');
    (function pullnewnumber(){
        $.ajax({
            context: this,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/fetchnewnumber/',
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: c,
                input: current_number
            },
            success: function(response) {
                var new_number = response.newNumber;
                $(".container").html(new_number);
            },
            complete: function(){
            setTimeout(pullnewnumber, 1000);
            }
        });
    });
```

**views.py**

```
def sampleView(request):
    if request.POST:
       if request.is_ajax():
          input_num = request.POST.get("input", "")
          if input_num < 10:
             num = input_num + 1
          json_object = {'responseNum': num}
          return JsonResponse(json_object)  
    else:
        num = 1
        return render_to_response('xyz_template.html',
                                 {'newNumber': num},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Hey there,

thanks for the reply,
I have some doubts,
1. in the html I need to include static files on the head, in this case js, right?
2. The pqr.js file only sets the value in the container?

Thanks again!

Comment: Yes! you need to include staticfiles and JS makes an ajax call to the URL and gets the new value of the number to be set on success..

Comment: This is massive overkill; OP just wants to display a simple counter.

Comment: Hello there! I just wanted to see how it could load data, I really want to change that data with data received from an Arduino, and this is the simplest way I can think, I think to take care of the rest, do you have a better solution?

thanks.

Comment: well.. Daniel.. i just wanted to make sure my answer helped in case JCH was working with Django and Ajax.. its a tricky subject.. well.. now that he seems to have mentioned Arduino.. The Question Title turns out to be misleading then.

Comment: yes, sorry, I think the title is wrong mentioning the Arduino, but it is my first post and in the instructions said I had to be precise, but Utkarsh your answer is exactly what I needed, really thanks